# Constructing a finite measure (positive top rank differential form with finite volume) on a smooth manifold

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $Q$ be an oriented smooth manifold. I am trying to construct a finite measure on $Q$, i.e. a top rank positive differential form with finite volume.

My idea is given a collection of local charts $(U_\alpha, \psi_\alpha)$, we can construct a positive $\mu_\alpha$ as $\mu_\alpha = f_\alpha dq^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dq^n$ for any positive smooth $f_\alpha$ on $U_\alpha$. Now using the paracompactness of any manifold, we can find a countable collection of regular coordinate balls that is an open locally finite refinement of $U_\alpha$. Say this collection is $(V_n)$. Then we can construct a global top rank form $\mu$ by a partition of unity subordinate to $V_n$, $$\mu = \sum_i \rho_i \mu_i.$$ I am trying to show that this has finite measure but I am struggling to finish the proof here. So we have
$\int_Q \mu = \sum_i \int_{V_i} \rho_i f_i dq^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dq^n = \sum_i \int_{\psi_i(V_i)}(\rho_i f_i \circ \psi_i^{-1})d^nq$ where $d^nq$ is the Lebesgue measure.I think I need to use the compactness of the domains but I can't figure out how to show that this integral can be finite, or come up with a different construction. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to expect $\int\mu$ to be finite in general.  For instance, imagine $Q=\mathbb{R}$ and every $\mu_i$ is just $dx$; then you'd be integrating $dx$ over all of $\mathbb{R}$ which diverges.

The trick, though, is that there is no reason you need to use $\rho_i$ themselves as the coefficients on the $\mu_i$.  All you care is that you pick some coefficients with compact support such that $\mu$ still ends up being nonzero everywhere.  So for instance, you could instead take $\mu=\sum c_i\rho_i\mu_i$ for any sequence of positive constants $c_i$.  If you choose the $c_i$ appropriately (e.g., choose $c_i$ so that $\int c_i\rho_i\mu_i=1/2^i$), you can make $\int\mu$ finite.